# Selecting attributes for field calculator by common name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, wildcard

I am trying to automate some of my GIS processes and have come across a snag in my automation. I am trying to understand the percent coverage of my suitability raster layer with my town boundaries layer after using the Tabulate Area tool.

Is there a way using Python for me to select all the attributes in my tabulate area tool using wildcards?

For example, sum all fields stating with "Value_*". Below is an example of the fields I need to join. Using the wildcard will help because I will not always know the exact name of the field I am looking to sum up.

```
( [VALUE_1] + [VALUE_11]+ [VALUE_101]+ [VALUE_111]+ [VALUE_1001]+ [VALUE_1011]+ [VALUE_1101]+ [VALUE_1111]+ [VALUE_1000]+ [VALUE_1002]+ [VALUE_1003]+ [VALUE_1004]+ [VALUE_1010]+ [VALUE_1012]+ [VALUE_1013]+ [VALUE_1014]+ [VALUE_1005]+ [VALUE_1006]+ [VALUE_1007]+ [VALUE_1008]+ [VALUE_1009]+ [VALUE_1015]+ [VALUE_1016]+ [VALUE_1017]+ [VALUE_1100]+ [VALUE_1102]+ [VALUE_1103]+ [VALUE_1104]+ [VALUE_1105]+ [VALUE_1106]+ [VALUE_1107]+ [VALUE_1108])/2,590,000
```

Comment: This would be fairly easy to do using a Search/UpdateCursor, are you bound to using the Field Calculator?

Comment: I am not bound to using the Field Calculator and actually decided to go another route and just use the zonal statistic by area tool. If there is a solution available, I would be curious, I guess I could use search or update cursor and perform the calculations manually.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could use a search cursor to find the sum of all fields beginning with "VALUE_":

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, '*') as cursor:
    fields = cursor.fields
    for row in cursor:
        total = sum(value for name, value in zip(fields, row) if name.startswith('VALUE_'))
```

(not tested)